# Running test cases to test a function using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to test few test cases for a function where it takes two parameters. these two parameters along with the result I have defined it in three different files and then exporting it. I am using Jest for the same, but it is throwing "TypeError: (0 , _index.default) is not a function" error. Can some one tell where I am going wrong. Testing this in the sandbox

test file:

```
import appendToFilter from "./index";
import { res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, res6, res7, res8 } from "./Results";
import { src1, src2, src3, src4, src5, src6, src7, src8 } from "./Source";
import { ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5, ip6, ip7, ip8 } from "./Input";

test("case1", () => {
  expect(appendToFilter(src1, ip1)).toBe(res1);
});
```

index.js

```
export function appendToFilter(filter, inputObjects) {
  // logic here
}
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-so-b47y8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the function as a default import but you exported it as a named export. Go to your index.js and

```js
export default appendToFilter
```

or import the function as the named import it is by doing:

```js
import { appendToFilter } from "./index";
```

instead of:

```js
import appendToFilter from "./index";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't have any default export and you are importing appendToFilter from index without named import.

use

```
import { appendToFilter } from "./index";
```

instead of

```
import appendToFilter from "./index";
```

Comment: the way you are doing it seems correct only i am not sure about what is logic in your function. generally you pass argument to your function expect your return value as expected based on your logic.

Comment: maybe you should create another question about how to test your function.

Comment: I think you are doing it right from what I see in your test file. What you need to keep an eye on is the assertions - toBe doesn't always work, you need to try other assertions like toEqual for some cases especially arrays and objects. Checkout the Jest documentation for more assertions you can try out